# Normal Mapping doesn't work

Tags: vim, macvim

For some reason, the following map is not working:

`nmap ,u :.g/./t.|s/./=/g<CR>`

It was intended that once I typed `,u` on a line like this:

```
lorem ipsum
```

It should transform into:

```
lorem ipsum
===========
```

The result: I see `:.g/./t.` in the bottom of the window. Then I tried escaping the `|`, and now once I use the mapping I simply see `:.g/./t.|s/./=/g` in the bottom, and nothing happens.

There probably is a better and error-free way to do it, I still a beginner.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape bar in mapping: either use `\|`, or `<bar>`. Now it is parsed as two commands: `nmap ,u :.g/./t.` and `s/./=/g<CR>`.

And do not use `nmap`, use `nnoremap`.

**Update**: though escaped variant of your mapping works, I would have written it as either `yyp:s/./=/g<CR>`, as `:call append('.', repeat('=', strdisplaywidth(getline('.'))))<CR>` (vim-7.3, best variant) or as `:call append('.', repeat('=', len(split(getline('.'), '\zs'))))<CR>` (vim-7.2, has just the same problems with tabs and fullwidth characters as `yyp...` variant, but does not overwrite any registers).

Comment: I'd go with `nnoremap ,u yyp:s/./=/g<CR>` or perhaps `nnoremap ,u yypv$r=` personally.

Comment: Thanks frabjous, this solution is great as well!